# if $f(x)$ is periodic $\left|\int_1^\infty f(x) x^{-s} dx\right| \sim C\left|\int_1^\infty \sin(x) x^{-s} dx\right|$ when $\text{Im}(s) \to \infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, gamma-function, dirichlet-series, mellin-transform

is it true that

> if $f(x)$ is periodic, non-constant and bounded  $$\text{when } T \to \infty ,\qquad\qquad\sup_{|t| \ <\ T}\ \  \left|\ \int_1^\infty f(x) x^{-\sigma-it} dx\ \right| \ \sim  \  C\left|\ \int_1^\infty  \sin(x) x^{-\sigma-it} dx\ \right|$$

$$ $$

EDIT : I just added the $\ \displaystyle\sup_{t \ <\ T}\ $ because it is false that

$$\text{when } t \to \infty,\qquad\qquad\left|\int_1^\infty f(x) x^{-\sigma-it} dx\right| \ \sim  \ C\left|\int_1^\infty  \sin(x) x^{-\sigma-it} dx\right| $$

the [Dirichlet $\eta$ and $\beta$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) are counter-examples :

$$\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} (-1)^{n+1} = s \int_1^\infty {}_{\_\_}\!|^{^{\!\_\_\!\_}}\!|\!{}_{\_\_}\!|^{^{\!\_\_\!\_}}(x) \ x^{-s-1} dx$$

$$\beta(s) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1)^{-s} (-1)^{n+1} = s \int_1^\infty {}_{\_\_}\!|^{^{\!\_\_\!\_}}\!|\!{}_{\_\_}\!|^{^{\!\_\_\!\_}}{\textstyle\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)} \ x^{-s-1} dx$$

on $\text{Re}(s) = 1$, the former has an infinity of zeros while the latter doesn't have any zero has says the [prime number theorem for Dirichlet characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function), so $\frac{\eta(1+it)}{1+it}$ cannot be equivalent to $\frac{\beta(1+it)}{1+it}$.

---

I'm aware that for $Re(s) > 0$ : $\Gamma(s) =  \int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{s-1} dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-ax} (ax)^{s-1} d(ax)$ for any $Re(a) > 0$ because the function $h(z) = e^{-z} z^{s-1}$ is analytic on $Re(z) \ge 0$ hence $\int_0^\infty + \int_\infty^{a\infty}+\int_{a\infty}^0 h(z) dz = 0$, and $h(z)$ decreases exponentially fast when $|z| \to \infty$ hence $\int_\infty^{a\infty} h(z) dz = 0$. by continuity, if $Re(s) < 1$ we can go until $a = \pm i = e^{\pm i \pi /2}$ and we get $\Gamma(s) = e^{i \pi s/2}\int_0^\infty e^{-ix} x^{s-1} dx = e^{-i \pi s/2}\int_0^\infty e^{ix} x^{s-1} dx$, hence where it converges, i.e. for $Re(s) \in ]0;2[$ : $\int_0^\infty \sin(x) x^{-s} dx = \sin{\textstyle\left(\frac{\pi(1-s)}{2}\right)} \Gamma(1-s)$ and $$\int_1^\infty \sin(x) x^{-s} = \sin{\textstyle\left(\frac{\pi(1-s)}{2}\right)} \Gamma(1-s) + \mathcal{O}(1)$$

I'm also aware that with the Fourier series expansion $f(x) = c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{ inx} + b_n e^{-inx}$ if everything is convergent, we get
$$\int_1^\infty f(x) x^{-s} dx = \frac{c_0}{s-1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{s-1} \int_n^\infty (a_n e^{ix}+b_n e^{-ix}) x^{-s} dx = \frac{c_0}{s-1} + \int_1^\infty (A_{1-s}(x) e^{ix} + B_{1-s}(x) e^{-ix}) dx$$

where $A_{1-s}(x) = \sum_{n \le x} a_n n^{s-1}$ and $B_{1-s}(x) = \sum_{n \le x} b_n n^{s-1}$ are the partial Dirichlet series.

Comment: What about $f=1$ or $f$ constant ?

Comment: @Thomas : that's what I'm trying to see, what are the conditions ensuring that we have the equivalence, and clearly you are right I need to add $f$ non-constant (thank you)

Comment: but what I'd really need is a good estimation of $\int_A^\infty e^{ix} x^{-s} dx$ when $Im(s) \to \infty$ (some sort of modified incomplete Gamma function) as the Fourier expansion of $f$ reduces to those kind of terms

Comment: @Thomas : now I remember why I didn't write that $f$ is non-constant : if  it is constant then where it converges : $\int_1^\infty f(x) x^{-s} dx  = \frac{f(0)}{s-1} \to C \int_1^\infty \sin(x) x^{-s} dx$ with $C = 0$, (hence in that case thereisn't equivalence)

Comment: If $f$ is say $2\pi$ periodic, did you try to write f a a sum of a Fourier series, and try to understand $\int _1^\infty e^{inx} x^{-s} ds$. You can use the change of variables $y=nx$.

Comment: @Thomas : yes but with $f(x) = c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{inx} + b_n e^{-inx}$ you'll get if everything is convergent :

$$\int_1^\infty f(x) x^{-s} dx = \frac{c_0}{s-1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{s-1} \int_n^\infty (a_n e^{ix}+b_n e^{-ix}) x^{-s} dx = \int_1^\infty (A_{1-s}(x) e^{ix} + B_{1-s}(x) e^{-ix}) dx$$

where $A_{1-s}(x) = \sum_{n \le x} a_n n^{s-1}$ and $B_{1-s}(x) = \sum_{n \le x} b_n n^{s-1}$. (hence it could be true only for certain $Re(s)$ and $f$ smooth, but it askes more work)

Comment: I can also get $ \Gamma(s) \int_1^\infty f(x) x^{-s} dx  = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \left(\int_1^\infty f(y) e^{-xy} dy \right) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{su} \left(\int_1^\infty f(y) e^{-e^u y} dy \right) du$ which is a Fourier transform, hence its asymptotics at $Im(s) \to \infty$ depends on the smoothness of $\int_1^\infty f(y) e^{-e^u y} dy $ @Thomas

Comment: @Thomas : pls excuse me if I'm bothering you, did you have an idea for understanding $\int_a^\infty e^{ix}x^{-s} dx$ when $Im(s) \to \infty$ ? $\Gamma(s,a,c) = \int_a^\infty e^{cx} x^{-s} dx$ is a generalization of the upper incomplete Gamma function, and when $Re(c) < 0$ it should keep most of its properties, but I see no reason why it would still be true when $Re(c) = 0$ ?

Comment: maybe that would be useful : with $x = by$ we get $\Gamma(s,a,c) = b^{1-s} \int_{a/b}^\infty e^{cby} y^{-s} dy = b^{1-s} \Gamma(s,a/b,bc)$. suppose it stays true even when $b$ is complex, then $\Gamma(s,a,i)  = i e^{-i \pi s/2}\Gamma(s,-ia,-1)$ which is the upper incomplete Gamma function

Comment: Probably the result depends on $a$ . Dis you tried the standard stationary phase method ? if $a=1$ or $a\not 1$ this yields very diffrent results.